# MongoDB Как найти массив с максимальным количеством объектов?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Есть несколько курсов. Как найти курс в котором количество юзеров будет наибольшим? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса